# pass variable into deferred done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to pass a variable into a `done` callback, but haven't had any luck.

```
var getDataForCompany = function(company_id) {

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: url,
      data:{
        company_id: company_id 
      }

    }).done(function(returnedData, textStatus, jqXHR) {

      anotherFn(company_id);
      //need to access company_id here, but it is undefined


    });

};
```

I tried wrapping the entire AJAX request in an IIFE to try to make a closure to capture my company_id, but

```
var getDataForCompany = function(company_id) {

    ($.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: url,
      data:{
        company_id: company_id 
      }

    }).done(function(returnedData, textStatus, jqXHR) {

      anotherFn(company_id);
      //need to access company_id here, but it is undefined


    })(company_id);

};
```

also failed to work. Is this not the correct method?

Comment: Maybe `company_id` is undefined ? because first example should work... How do you call `getDataForCompany` ?

Comment: Try a simple `console.log(company_id)` before the ajax call to see if it is or not.

Comment: BTW, where do you define the url?

Comment: @FrancescoE. Yeah, i just jotted down some pseudo-code. `url` is defined.

Comment: @Alexander Absolutely right. Answer was in plain site. Thanks very much.

Comment: @1252748 - can you post the working code from your question as an answer with a note explaining why it wasn't working. You can then accept that answer and this question will be more useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the anonymous done function should have a reference to the company_id passed in with the getDataForCompany call.  It probably is just undefined when it is being passed in.  The code below is similar to the closure setup of your ajax call.  If you run the method you will see that the company_id will be logged.

```
var getDataForCompany = function(company_id) {

    var done  = function() {
        console.log(company_id)
    }

    done();
};





getDataForCompany("ID")
>>"ID"
getDataForCompany()
>>undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var getDataForCompany = function(company_id) {
    return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data:{
        company_id: company_id
      }
    })
    .done(function(returnedData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      var company_id = this.url.split(/company_id=/)[1];
      console.log(company_id);
      return anotherFn(company_id);
      //need to access company_id here, but it is undefined
    });
};
```

```js
var anotherFn = function(company_id) {
  return $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/23e61e522a14d45a35e1/raw/62775b7420f8df6b3d83244270d26495e40a1e9d/ticker.json",
      data:{
        company_id: JSON.stringify(company_id)
      },
      dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
       console.log(this.url.split(/company_id=/)[1])
    })
  };

var getDataForCompany = function(company_id) {

    return $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/23e61e522a14d45a35e1/raw/62775b7420f8df6b3d83244270d26495e40a1e9d/ticker.json",
      data:{
        company_id: company_id
      },
      dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(returnedData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      var company_id = this.url.split(/company_id=/)[1];
      console.log(company_id);
      return anotherFn(parseInt(company_id) + 1);
      //need to access company_id here, but it is undefined


    });

};

  getDataForCompany(1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```